# get dynamic input value with php

Tags: php

i need to create links containing  hidden input with different names on each links.

```
 <?php
    $inputCounter=0;
    .. do while... 
    {
        $inputCounter++; ?>
        <a href="read.php">
            <input hidden name="rec<?php echo $inputCounter ;?>" 
                     value="<?php echo $id' ;?>"/>
            read    
        </a> 
    <?php } ?>
```

how to get the input value  in read.php ? 
thank you for any help.

Comment: Does read.php output anything?  Is it a function? How does read.php relate to `$inputCounter`?

Comment: Change your link in your `a` tag into something like `<a href="read.php?rec=' . <?php echo $inputCounter ;?> . '">`

Comment: The question is very unclear. What exactly do you wish to achieve?

Comment: @Onimusha i need to get the value of the input, for example echoing in read.php, the  input value of the link clicked.

Comment: @FreeSoul Try my answer below and see if it works?

Comment: @romo the $inputCounter is to give every input created a different name which i want to get later in read.php, something like $inputValue=$_POST['rec1']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not place an input in an anchor tag. Use query string to pass values along.

```html
<a href="read.php?name=rec<?=$inputCounter?>&value=<?=$id?>">read</a>
```

Then on `read.php`, read your data using [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).

```php
$name = $_GET['name'] // gives you the name
$value = $_GET['value'] // gives you the value
```

To echo the value, just do

```
echo $value;
```

Comment: actually what i'm trying to achieve is not to show the id in the url. But thanks for your help :)